# Let user input a value in a cell containing a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: table1]

I'm not very familiar with google sheets yet, and I am looking for a way to allow users to input a value in one of the 4 cells containing a formula. Then the other cells would update according to the value the user entered in the cell he chose.

So if a user enters a value in B2 : B3 B4 and B5 would run the formula according to B2's value. And if then if he chooses to enter another value for B4 : B2 B3 and B5 would update accordingly.

I am not sure if what I have in mind is the correct way to do this, or if it is even possible at all. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just answer according to my understanding, maybe I'm wrong to understand. I think you just paste your formula's in column c and allow your users to put values in B column, this is the way formula do automatic it for you. Sorry for bad English
I mean to put this in column c `=B4/4` like bellow

[image]

and you get result like bellow

[image]

Comment: sorry for the delayed answer, yeah this seems to be the simplest way to do what I want, i'll implement it like you did. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have custom inputs for values **B2**, **B3**, **B4**, **B5** populate these cells with numbers and put your formulas in **C** column:

[image]

---

if you want to have custom inputs for values **4**, **60**, **30** then do it like this:

[image: 0]